# XPath length of string

Tags: xml, xpath

I'm looking for the solution of a problem.

I have xml file and i'd like to find length of titles of each Film

i tried

```
string-length(/Repertuar/Film/Title)
```

but i got only one length (=10). It should be

10

14

XML File

```
 <Repertuar>
  <Film ID="080154">
    <Title>Wolny król</Title>
    <Rezyser Imie="Rambert" Nazwisko="Rochus"/>
    <Budżet>130507000</Budżet>
    <RokProdukcji>2015</RokProdukcji>
    <Dlugosc>103</Dlugosc>
    <Gatunek>Familijny</Gatunek>
    <Obsada>
      <Aktor Imie="Valtteri" Nazwisko="Atticus"/>
      <Aktor Imie="Rihard" Nazwisko="Yasamin"/>
    </Obsada>
    <Projekcja>
      <Czas>
        <Wtorek Godzina="18"/>
        <Sroda Godzina="18"/>
        <Czwartek Godzina="19"/>
      </Czas>
      <CenaBiletu>15</CenaBiletu>
      <NrSali>3</NrSali>
    </Projekcja>
  </Film>
  <Film ID="081435">
    <Title>Podwójny honor</Title>
    <Rezyser Imie="Clarence" Nazwisko="Pavli"/>
    <Budżet>240567000</Budżet>
    <RokProdukcji>2016</RokProdukcji>
    <Dlugosc>130</Dlugosc>
    <Gatunek>Wojenny</Gatunek>
    <MinWiek>16</MinWiek>
    <Obsada>
      <Aktor Imie="Prisca" Nazwisko="Tezcatlipoca"/>
      <Aktor Imie="Naila" Nazwisko="Tymon"/>
      <Aktor Imie="Pooja" Nazwisko="Jitendra"/>
      <Aktor Imie="Vidya" Nazwisko="Wigmar"/>
    </Obsada>
    <Projekcja>
      <Czas>
        <Poniedzialek Godzina="20"/>
        <Sroda Godzina="20"/>
        <Piatek Godzina="20"/>
      </Czas>
      <CenaBiletu>20</CenaBiletu>
      <NrSali>2</NrSali>
    </Projekcja>
  </Film>

</Repertuar>
```

XPath tester
    http://codebeautify.org/Xpath-Tester

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible with XPath 1.0

With XPath 2.0 you can do this:

```
/Repertuar/Film/Title/string-length(.)
```

or if you need more complex processing for each node:

```
for $i in /Repertuar/Film/Title return string-length($i)
```